# How do i can remove extra spaces and correct the words in Microsoft office word document

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, office365

I need to copy an assignment from scribd.com. [Here](http://www.scribd.com/doc/51153775/Nanoparticles-assignment#scribd) is the URL of that assignment.

But when I am trying to copy this assignment and paste it into my local word file it looks like this:

```
s ca
ll
ed as Lycurgus cup . Th
i
s cup had go
l
d c
l
us
t
ers on
it

t
o crea
t
e d
i
fferen
t
co
l
ors on
it
.[3]
```

how can i set it, suggest me any tool or online tools.

Comment: You could always download the file as a .docx

Answer (score 0):

Try using chrome or firefox to copy and paste.

I used chrome and it pasted like this:

> The nano-scale size materials also cannot be lingered. According to this, it cannot be predicted that the purity of the application area of the nanoparticles. To be sure, it should besome analysis done, if it will be thinken for large scales, it can not be possible.[13],[15]